# Pig: How to access fields from multiple tuples from a bag

Tags: apache-pig

**My Pig Script:**

```
A = LOAD 'average.txt' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(.\*?)\\s+(.\*?)\\s+(.*?) AS TUPLE(AA:chararray,BB:chararray,CC:chararray);  
C = FILTER B BY tuple_0.AA IS NOT NULL;  
D = GROUP C BY $0.AA;
```

**Output after group stmt:**

```
(1,{((1,a,b)),((1,c,d))})  
(2,{((2,e,f)),((2,g,h))})
```

**I need final output like this:**

```
(1,a,b,c,d)  
(2,e,f,g,h)
```

**Describe query:**

```
| D     | group:chararray     | C:bag{:tuple(tuple_0:tuple(AA:chararray,BB:chararray,CC:chararray))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of grouping on $0.AA, I would suggest to do a self join on C as below:

```
A = LOAD 'average.txt' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(.\*?)\\s+(.\*?)\\s+(.*?) AS     TUPLE(AA:chararray,BB:chararray,CC:chararray);  
C = FILTER B BY tuple_0.AA IS NOT NULL;  
C = FOREACH C GENERATE tuple_0.AA AS AA, tuple_0.BB AS BB, tuple_0.CC AS CC; --renaming columns to easy names

D = FOREACH C GENERATE AA, BB, CC;  -- clone of C

CD = JOIN C BY AA, D BY AA;
CD2 = FOREACH CD 
         GENERATE 
            C::AA AS AA, 
            C::BB AS CBB, 
            C::CC AS CCC, 
            D::BB AS DBB,
            D::CC AS DCC;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Gaurav, thanks for your suggestion. i will apply your logic and let you know the output.

Comment: @SivasakthiJayaraman, I hope my answer helped you. Please mark your question answered if it helped.